# Make image draggable but fit exactly parent containment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i want to know how work facebook new timeline image reposition with jquery?

this example is similar to facebook image dragging but this is not working with image size limit: http://oneblackbear.com/draggable/index.html

i want same facebook image reposition code.

Thanks

Comment: *"but this is now working with image size limit"* what does this mean? *"i want same facebook image reposition code."* are you seroius?

Comment: sorry, actualy i want drag image within div not out of div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### *[Try this demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/hMmbK/1/)*

```
$(".image_drag img").draggable({

    stop: function(ev, ui) {
        var hel = ui.helper, pos = ui.position;
        //horizontal
        var h = -(hel.outerHeight() - $(hel).parent().outerHeight());
        if (pos.top >= 0) {
            hel.animate({ top: 0 });
        } else if (pos.top <= h) {
            hel.animate({ top: h });
        }
        // vertical
        var v = -(hel.outerWidth() - $(hel).parent().outerWidth());
        if (pos.left >= 0) {
            hel.animate({ left: 0 });
        } else if (pos.left <= v) {
            hel.animate({ left: v });
        }
    }

});
```

---

Or you can set manually the containment for your element:

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/hMmbK/2/)*

```
$("img").draggable({ containment: [-99, -119, 0, 0], scroll: false });
```

Comment: First example helpful. can you make 2nd example automatic like first example?

Comment: @anosim Than use the second one!

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to calculate the image W/H dynamically you can do it like: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/hMmbK/3/

Comment: Problem Again. when i add <div id="container"> before 2nd example it's not working fine.

Comment: sure it works, you just have to set manually the containment. As I already said before. In that case should be approx. `[-91, -99, 0, 0]`